# If i create an array of text elements dynamically is it going to be indexed by Googlebot?

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, googlebot

I have some text actually 20+ pieces of large text and i add it into an array

```
var translation = new Array();
translation [0] = "<p>English</p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit"
translation [1] = "<p>French</p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit"
translation [2] = "<p>German</p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit"
translation [3] = "<p>Italian</p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit"
```

and then i want to call them like that -

```
$('<div/>', {
class: "trpanel",
html: translation[0],
 })
.appendTo('body');
```

it will be a bit more complicated than that because you will be able to see each text  according to what you have seen before. But that doesn't matter at this stage. 
What i am interested in is if in the future this text will be searchable by google. I am a rookie obviously but i could add all these as hidden html elements change class and show them instead when needed. What is the best solution for being indexed by google? I very much prefer to have them in my .js file whithout the need to search each time for each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not be indexed.

To help SEO in dynamic text, you might use a different approach.

Instead of an array of strings in javascript code, create all the text in the html page, using html elements; and dynamically set its visibility.

For example, see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zVTKq/2/

it shows how to select from a set of `div`s placed insiden an invisible `div` container, and selectively displays the appropiate text

```
$('#translated').html($("#translation-en").html());
```

Comment: That's great! thank you, and i can create an array from the id's to do all of my mathematical hocus pocus in jquery.